# need help in removing extra line for python reverse triangle loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Below is the code for my reverse triangle loop, when I run the code extra empty line is created. I need help in removing the extra empty line so that each function will only have once empty new line. the function needs to look like the image below

**Image**

```
***********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```

**The Code:**

```
def triangle (height):
    return height
num=11
print()
for i in range(num,0,-2):
    for j in range(0,num-i):
        print(end=(" "*2))
    for j in range(0,i):
        print("*",end=(" "*2))
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Try removing the final line: print("\n")

Comment: @Bug That does not solve the problem. Try it for yourself.

Comment: try changing `print("\n")` to just use `print()`

Comment: @downshift That also produces a weird effect.

Comment: Have sorted and posted as answer

Comment: What weird effect @ifconfig? Looks normal to me here: https://repl.it/Jo7m

Answer (score 1):

```
def triangle(height):
    for index, i in enumerate(range(height, 0, -1)):
        print(end=" " * index)

        print("* " * i)

triangle(5)
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    * 

triangle(10)
* * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * 
     * * * * * 
      * * * * 
       * * * 
        * * 
         *
```

Comment: Recommend changing `-1` to `-2` and `* ` to `*`, as it produces a better effect for answering the OP.

Comment: The code will only work for odd numbers then or it wont have the final single *